# Confused about Google Apps accounts

Tags: google-workspace, google-app-engine

I'm mostly interested in using Google App Engine for a public-facing website but I'm confused as heck about how Google wants me to structure my accounts.

When Google App Engine launched, I played around with it using my regular GMail account and deploying to foo.appspot.com. At one point I wanted to use a custom domain (realmode.com). Using a custom domain requires signing up for Google Apps, which I did. I was asked to verify my account by typing in a code sent to my phone.

Fast forward to the present. I decided to use Google App Engine for a real website (strokeproduction.com). I signed up for Google Apps using this domain. I completed the various DNS tasks to prove I owned the domain, redirect strokeproduction.com to www.strokeproduction.com and set up A-records to point www.strokeproduction.com to the IP address Google required. Then I went to deploy a GAE app under this new account.

When I clicked Create Application, Google wanted me to verify my new account by sending a code to my phone. I entered my phone number, but it complained that I'd already used that phone number for a different account. Well, ok, that's true.

**Am I not supposed to have more than one Google Apps account?** I wouldn't mind just using my regular old GMail account except that would mean giving my personal password to anyone with the ability to deploy to strokeproduction.com.

What I'm trying to do—having a Google Apps account for more than one project, but having only one phone—doesn't seem like it would be unusual. **How am I supposed to set up accounts to handle this?**

Comment: When are you required to do a phone verification?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what exactly you want to do here! anyways, here's what I got from your comment (!)

You hosted a website on Google App Engine (GAE), and pointed your custom domain to your GAE website using Google Apps.

As far I remember, only GAE asks for mobile verification, and in Google Apps you only have to verify that you own the domain.

You can have multiple apps in GAE and also you can link multiple domains to your Google Apps account.

Ah... see if this helps: https://www.google.com/search?q=multiple+domains+google+apps

Comment: what am I supposed to look for in that Google search results? [se] websites rank fairly high in Google, pointing them to a Google search isn't helping anyone

Comment: I meant the first result http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=182452 well, ofc if your problem is adding multiple domains to one Google Apps account...

Comment: I think he wants to set up for every website separately. This is the better way of organizing them as 2 of his website probably have nothing to do with each other.

Answer (score -1):

From what i understand he wants to create a seperate Google account with all the Google App Engine stuff under so he can share this account with everyone who needs to access the Instance.

There is a easy way of doing goto the app engine management and on the left you will find a option to change permissions to be exact ( Administration->permissions)
There you can invite other people gmail accounts to manage the instance and you can specify exactly what they have permissions to change and do.

If you are trying to create this using Google Apps account http://www.google.com/Apps and you cant connect it up to google app engine and cant use another phone to verify the account then you will have to open a support ticket with Google.

The Reason why they only allow one cellphone number per google apps account is because they have a free zone(or something similar to amazons freezone) and do not want people abusing it byt being able to launch as many servers as they want for free.